# laravel eloquent retrieve part of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Im working on an application using eloquent for retrieving models.

**Status**

Lets assume I have a model for **GROUP,PERSON,HOBBY**.

All these are connected 1:n

```
GROUP 1---n PERSON

PERSON 1---n HOBBY
```

The approach could be to retrieve the model:

```
$group = Group::find(123)->with('persons.hobbies')->get();
```

To display the model in my template I would fire my group to the template. Then I would iterate over my persons in that group and also over my hobbies to for example display the
name of the hobby.

**Question**

As this model is very(!) trivial. I would like to know if it is possible(useless or not) to retrieve directly(not nested) all the hobbies(as an array of Eloquent models). But still the only thing I know is the Group(i.e. groupId) at the beginning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because 1---n relationship between `group` and `person` could return many `person` objects for a given `group_id` . It is not possible to access a list of hobbies of something that is a collection.

If you really want to  do this 'directly', my suggestion would be that you use Fluent. the query builder, instead of Eloquent, to join the tables.

Something like:

```
DB::select('hobby.*')
  ->from('hobby')
  ->join('group', 'group.id = person.group_id')
  ->join('person', 'person.hobby_id = hobby.id')
  ->where('group.id', $group_id);
```